# Promises With Google Maps Geocoder API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, es6-promise

Im trying to create a set of functions that translates a set of addresses to lat long values using the Google Maps Geocoder API.

Currently, I have it successfully translating the addresses to lat long values but the function fully executes before theyre returned. I know this because it throws undefined errors before it logs the proper lat long values after.

I heard that javascripts promises can be a solution to this type of problem so I did a little bit of research but it doesn't seem to be helping the issues. Im new to promises so excuse me if Im going about this in the wrong way.

Here`s the relevant code

```
 function getPoints(geocoder,map) {
       let locationData = [];
       let latValue;
       for(let i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++){
            let getLatLong = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                 latValue = findLatLang(addressData[i].location, geocoder, map);
                 if(latValue!=undefined){
                      resolve(latValue());
                 } else {
                      reject();
                 }
            });
            getLatLong.then(function(){
                 console.log(latValue);
                 //returns a GMap latLng Object.
                 locationData.push( new google.maps.LatLng(latValue[0],latValue[1]));
            })
       }
       return locationData;
  }

function findLatLang(address, geocoder, mainMap) {
       geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                 console.log(results);
                 return [results[0].geometry.location.lat , results[0].geometry.location.lng];
            } else {
                 alert('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + address);
                 return;
            }
       })
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers you would have!

Comment: @Jaya inside of the for loop in getPoints there is a promise called getLatLong. Again I only watched a few videos so I may be using this completely wrong.

Comment: Oops just saw that. Also you have a promise inside a loop and the loop will iterate before it could execute your `then`. So you need to modify your code a bit. let me provide sample

Comment: Push all your promises in an array, then wait for them all, but do you want it to processed parallely or one after the other?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your main issue is that `geocoder.geocode()` is asynchronous and takes a callback. You are passing a function to the callback but treating the return value as if it will return from the main function, `findLatLang()`, but it won't. Currently `findLatLang()` returns nothing.

`findLatLang()` is where you should have the promise and return it from the function:

```
function findLatLang(address, geocoder, mainMap) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                console.log(results);
                resolve([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + address));
            }
    })
    })
}
```

Then in the loop in `getPoints()` you can just collect those promises into an array and call `Promise.all()` on the array which will give you the values once all promises have resolved:

```
function getPoints(geocoder,map) {
    let locationData = [];
    let latValue;
    for(let i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++){
        locationData.push(findLatLang(addressData[i].location, geocoder, map))
    }
    return locationData // array of promises
}

var locations = getPoints(geocoder,map)

Promise.all(locations)     
.then(function(returnVals){
        // you should have return values here when
        // all promises have rsolved
          console.log(returnVals);
})
```

It's not clear where `addressData` is coming from - you are using it in the function, but it's not being passed in anywhere.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/knmtogp6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var addressData = [{
  location: "New York, NY, USA"
}, {
  location: "Newark, NJ, USA"
}];

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var coordinates = [{}];
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function findLatLang(address, geocoder, mainMap) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          console.log(results);
          resolve([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + address));
        }
      })
    })
  }

  function getPoints(geocoder, map) {
    let locationData = [];
    let latValue;
    for (let i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++) {
      locationData.push(findLatLang(addressData[i].location, geocoder, map))
    }
    return locationData // array of promises
  }

  var locations = getPoints(geocoder, map)

  Promise.all(locations)
    .then(function(returnVals) {
      // you should have return values here when
      // all promises have rsolved
      console.log(returnVals);
      coordinates = returnVals;
      returnVals.forEach(function(latLng) {
        console.log(latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: latLng[0],
            lng: latLng[1]
          },
          map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      })
    })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: addressData is a global json data var that Im using for testing! Im reading through the question right now to understand how it works then Ill let you know if it works! Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: awesome! This worked with a little bit of tweaking! The Promise.all function seems like it`ll be super useful in the future